# Dijit dialog fires onshow event before visible

Tags: dialog, dojo, display

I've got myself trying to create a dialog with a progress bar in dojo.

When it is visible, on an onshow event, I want to trigger a recursive function to process code, and update the progress bar.  Problem is, the onshow fires before the dialog is visible, and the recursive processing completes and destroys the dialog with progress bar before it even becomes visible

Here's a vague code sample (ignore some of the custom classes, like panelManager, etc. When the dialog shows, I have a function I wish to call..

```
register_dialog = panelManager.getActive();
        //createPanel(panelManager.getActive().domNode, true, '', "Number of " + text_correction("Sample")+"s Registered", '', null, 90, 290, null, false, null);
        dialog = new dialog_simple({
            title: "Number of " + text_correction("Sample")+"s Registered",
            isLayoutContainer: true,
            containerNode: register_dialog.domNode,
            href: "blank.html",
            preload: true,
            parseOnLoad: true
        }); 


        dialog.domNode.style.width = "290px";
        dialog.domNode.style.height = "70px";

        progress = new ProgressBar({
            style: "width:270px",
            id: "register_progress",
            maximum: numOfSamples,
            value: 0,
            label: "0 of " +numOfSamples
        });
        dialog.on("show", function() {
            startRegister(theJSON, theHeaderData, currentSample, theSamples, dialog, progress, register_dialog);
        });
        dialog.on("cancel", function() {
            dijit.registry.remove(progress.id);
            progress.destroy();
            dialog.destroyRecursive()

        });
        dialog.set("content",progress);
        progress.startup();
        dialog.startup();
        dialog.show();
```

ANYWAY, it fires the function before the dialog is visible... ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific which Dialog are we talking about? I am not able to understand `dialog_simple`.

Comment: @TKambi I looked at the original source code and he is referring to dojox/widget/DialogSimple